# Handle php errors

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to catch and throw php errors as an exception

```
set_exception_handler(function($e){
 echo $e->getMessage(); 
});

register_shutdown_function(function() {
  $error = error_get_last();
  if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
    throw new ErrorException($error['message'], 0);
  }
});

notExistingFunction();
```

The problem is that ErrorException is not "catched" by my exception handler and I get

```
Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function notExistingFunction()'
```

instead of a nice message.

Comment: You cannot catch an exception thrown in the shutdown handler. The point of that handler is to be called as a last resort when terminating script execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_exception_handler( 'ExceptionHandler' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

In your case:

```
set_exception_handler( 'notExistingFunction' );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
     //your code
} catch (Exception $e) {
     //do something with errr
}
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I'm trying to achieve